# How can I 3 columns inside a column using jspdf?

Tags: jspdf-autotable

I need a little help related to autotable.I am using JSPDF library and I want to generate 3 columns(Fatal,Non-Fatal and Property Damage) horizontally under the column 2017.I tried to find through internet but could not find any solution.

```
doc.setFontStyle('normal');
doc.setFontSize(12);
   var columns = [
       { title: "Month", dataKey: "Month" },
       { title: "2017", dataKey: "2017" },



    ];

   var vehicle=[{'Month':'January','2017':'Fatal'},{'Month':'February'},{'Month':'March'},{'Month':'April'},{'Month':'May'},{'Month':'June'},{'Month':'July'},{'Month':'August'},{'Month':'September'},{'Month':'October'},{'Month':'November'},{'Month':'December'}];

   doc.autoTable(columns,vehicle, { 
        startY:55,
       margin: {horizontal: 5},
    bodyStyles: {valign: 'middle'},
    styles: {overflow: 'linebreak'},
    theme: 'grid',
    columnStyles: {
        text: {
            columnWidth: 'wrap'
        },
        Month: {
            columnWidth: '10',
            fontStyle: 'bold',
            textColor: 40 ,
            valign: 'left'
        },
        2017: {
            columnWidth: '20',
            fontStyle: 'bold',
            textColor: 40 ,
            valign: 'left'

    }
    });

    doc.save('Accident.pdf');
   }
```